# Only loads on the contact template page

Tags: javascript, footer, performance

In the footer i load the Google maps api. But only on the contact page, i used the google maps api. Now i want to make code. That the google maps api is only load in the contact template pages. How can i make that.

This is the script tag in the footer.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

That script tag. Must only load in the template contact page.

Thank for helping

Answer (score 3):

First a bit of advise (since the solution is based on it) - always "enqueue" your scripts, don't just add them in the footer. [Read this](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress-themes), for example . 
Now the solution for loading scripts on specific **template**, since this is what you asked for:

```
function enqueue_themescrits()
{
    if ( is_page_template('contact.php') ) { //the file your contact page uses
         wp_register_script( 'google_maps', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false' );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'google_maps' );
    }
    //Your other enqueued scripts

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_themescrits' );
```

**EDIT:** add this to your functions.php

Comment: No need to `register` the script, when A) the function contains nothing else than this process and B) you enqueue right after it. If you only enqueue it, then it's the same.

Answer (score 2):

You've got [»Conditional Tags«](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) in WordPress. Those allow you do determine if some condition meets or not (basically those are parts of the `$wp_query` object, just wrapped with a public API function).

In detail: There's [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page), which tells you if you're on the desired page not.

So just wrap it into a function, hook in at the right hook and abort if you're not on the desired page.

The following goes into your functions.php file (or a small custom plugin).

```
/** Plugin Name: Register Google Maps Script */
function wpse65356_enqueue_gmaps()
{
    if ( ! is_page( 'contact' ) )
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script(
         'google-maps'
        ,'maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false'
        ,array()
        ,0
        ,true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse65356_enqueue_gmaps' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript (and css) should be added with [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).
[Register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) the script but don't enqueue it yet in `functions.php`.

Call the enqueue on the contact template page before `wp_head()`,
which should be located in `header.php` so before `get_header()`.

`registering` and `queueing` is confusing at first here is a good [tutorial](http://halfelf.org/2012/jquery-why-u-no-enqueued/)

Comment: @kaiser my bad, fixed